# Android ripple effect on lower API

Tags: android, android-layout, rippledrawable

I am looking forward to develop ripple effect on android views.

I have searched a lot and found that it is possible in Android Lollipop using the [`RippleDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html). Is there an equivalent feature available when targeting a lower API version?